# How do I stop Teamviewer from flickering in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, teamviewer

Teamviewer keeps flickering in Ubuntu Unity 18.04 remoting from Windows

Answer (score 4):

You have to uncheck "Allow Flipping" in nvidia-settings

[image]